# Booting an older kernel in Xen DomU when using pvgrub in Dom0

Tags: xen, boot, kernel

I'm having issues with the lastest kernel update in a Debian Jessie DomU, and want to boot it using a previous kernel.

Dom0 is also running Debian Jessie, and is booting the DomU via PvGrub. I'm using the setup described in the [Debian wiki for PvGrub](https://wiki.debian.org/PvGrub), with the DomU's grub.cfg produced in the Dom0's skeleton directory.

This setup works perfectly to boot with the most recently installed kernel on the DomU, but seems to provide no way to select an older installed kernel to boot with, and I've yet to find any documentation on this topic.

So, given this setup, what is the recommended way to boot with an older installed kernel on the DomU?

DomU kernel config on the Dom0:

```
kernel          = '/usr/lib/grub-xen/grub-x86_64-xen.bin'
extra           = '(hd1)/boot/grub/grub.cfg'
root            = ''
```

grub.cfg on the DomU:

```
root='(xen/xvda2)'
insmod xzio
insmod gzio
insmod btrfs
insmod ext4
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/xvda2 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the grub.cfg is generated during system installation and doesn't need to be created manually. At least on my debian buster VMs it works out of the box.

Grub uses a structure called menuentry to group entries to multiple boot configurations. With this you can have multiple entries with different kernels.
For example my debian buster vm uses the following kernel configuration:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-6-amd64
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-6-amd64
```

The version numbers have to match your installed kernel. If you have uninstalled your previous kernel, try to install it using the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about newer releases, but running `xen-create-image` from a Debian Jessie Dom0 doesn't install the common grub packages on the DomU, and as far as I can tell, the skeleton `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` listed in the question just doesn't offer any ability to select a different kernel on boot.

I eventually solved this by doing the following on the DomU:

1. `mv /boot/grub /boot/grub.orig`
2. `apt-get install grub-pc`
3. Set grub-install to automatically run on the boot drive

Then I shut down the DomU, booted it with an attached console from the Dom0, and selected the kernel I wanted.